# Update array using ngModel and ngFor

Tags: html, angular, frontend, ngfor, ngmodel

I am trying to read an array's values onto the form and then be able to update that **same** (`toDos`) array's values (so having `name="todos{{i}}"` within the `<input>` won't work because it makes it a string and not an array) The code right now only reads and updates the LAST index of the array.

my array is:
`toDos: string[] =["Todo1","Todo2","Todo3"]`

my html is:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let todo of toDos; let i = index">
      <ul>
          <input class="form-control" name="toDo" [(ngModel)]="toDos[i]"  placeholder="To Do" style="border:none;">
      </ul>

</div>
```

Below is a screenshot of the current code and output. On submit I am printing the contents of `toDos` OG array and then the new updated content (which is only the last index)

[HTML and Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bjN8.png)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be several issues you are having.

**1. [(ngModel)] is possibly used in a Form**

Using [(ngModel)] in a form is what is causing only the last element to show up repeatably. There are special rules when you use ngModel in a Form

**2. Updating one item refreshes the entire array**

When you update an element in the array angular will by default replace the entire array. This would cause an issue where you can only enter 1 character and all inputs would be reloaded. You can bypass this by using a custom trackBy function, so angular knows you are only updating an element. [Read more about the trackBy function](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5).

**Code**

***app.component.html***

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let todo of toDos; let i = index; trackBy: trackBy">
      <ul>
          <input class="form-control" name="toDo" [(ngModel)]="toDos[i]"  placeholder="To Do" style="border:none;">
      </ul>
</div>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  toDos: string[] =["Todo1","Todo2", "Todo3"]
  log(){
    console.log(this.toDos)
  }
  trackBy(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

[Check out a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-up1stq)

Comment: Yes! I am trying to use it within a form because upon submit I was doing stuff with the data `(submit)="onSubmit(form)`